# How to install and configure byobu in HPC environment (i.e. no root)?

Tags: non-root-user, byobu

I am used to the byobu layout in Ubuntu and I suffer from the fact, that all the HPC I have access to in my work have no byobu (and sometimes even no screen/tmux).

I am able to build byobu from sources on each machine (for reproducibility purposes let's say I get byobu built using [Spack](http://spack.readthedocs.io/) with `spack install byobu`).

But neither way of getting it gives me a running byobu out-of-the-box. Even copying the configuration files from my Ubuntu didn't help (maybe they are not compatible?).

After the built the first thing it complains is

```
/cfs/fs2/home/users/aryczkowski/tmp/spack/opt/spack/linux-scientific6-x86_64/gcc-7.2.0/byobu-5.123-ieklnf3sogj4idrjdyr2bwcv7b6znr3h/bin/byobu: line 52: /cfs/fs2/home/users/aryczkowski/.local/lib/byobu/include/common: No such file or directory
```

(`/cfs/fs2/home/users/aryczkowski` is my `$HOME`).

When I create it with

```
mkdir -p /cfs/fs2/home/users/aryczkowski/.local/lib/byobu/include
touch /cfs/fs2/home/users/aryczkowski/.local/lib/byobu/include/common
```

It produces the following error message:

```
$ byobu
install: cannot create regular file `/printscreen': Permission denied
```

Copying "factory" byobu's settings from Ubuntu (`/usr/share/byobu/ -> $HOME/.local/share/byobu`, `/usr/lib/byobu -> $HOME/.local/lib/byobu`) generates other errors.

How to configure byobu to have it running, preferably with similar behavior and layout as in Ubuntu?

Specifically, does byobu need anything besides its sources to run? Does it need some configuration files, that need to be created manually?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro You are right. Here you are. Perhaps you can help me in essence as well?...

Comment: Would you be able to edit it for addressing more specific concerns?  This is will be closed easily per our FAQ in the future by moderation as "Requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic.".

Comment: It would be helpfull if this question has the code to isntall byobu from source

Comment: @gota But this is from source. Spack installs everything from source.

Comment: but I don't have spack installed. Maybe my HPC has different flavours of linux?

Comment: @gota You don't need any additional privileges to use Spack. Just  visit https://github.com/spack/spack and see if that works for you.